# Unused Potiential for Parallelisation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use a queue returned from a `tf.train.shuffle_batch` call for training in TensorFlow. I had assumed that TF would prefetch the next batch while performing calculations with the current batch on the GPU. I.e., I imagined a flow like this

- load batch A on CPU
- use batch A on GPU, *while* loading batch B on CPU
- use batch B on GPU, *while* loading batch C on CPU
- ...

However, looking at the tracing output, this does not seem to be the case:

[image: Trace]

For most of the `QueueDequeueMany` operation, the GPU is idle.

---

Is something like what I envision even possible with TensorFlow and if so: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that FIFOQueue is CPU-only so prefetching only works on CPU.
However you can implement your own prefetching by creating GPU variables and copying stuff from FIFO queue onto GPU variables in parallel, and then relying on those variables instead of the queue for GPU input. Here's an implementation of this idea by Tim Zaman:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5722#issuecomment-266297116

Comment: Nice, thanks for that link! I'll check it out later today

Answer (score 0):

I don't think TensorFlow is currently doing this optimization. Would be worth filing a feature request (TensorFlow github issue). One potential cost for such optimization is the increased memory footprint for additional buffering for the next batch.